# Apache Solr link to uploaded file not working

Tags: apache, solr, download

I have successfully install Apache Solr and uploaded pdf and doc files using the command

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=id&commit=true" -F      "myfile=@filename.pdf"
```

files get uploaded and results are displayed as per the query but when I click on file name it gives **404 error** saying resoure does not exist.

**I want to add custom field to be displayed along with contents of file, I want a link of file path to displayed along with the search result**

Any pointers or suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Solr does not store the file. So you have to host the file and the url to be able to download the file.

Answer (score 4):

Solr does not store the complete file as is.
It just stores the extracted content.
So you can only display those unformatted text.

Also, Solr can't link the file uploaded.
You would need to host these files to be download from http and use that url as additional metadata with indexing to enable the file download.